# Format column of integers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I want to first cast this column of integers to a string, but then have each single-digit integer formatted with 2 significant figures.

I want this:

```
>>> df[0].astype(str)
0          0
1          1
2          2
3          10
4          11
5          12
```

To become this:

```
>>> df[0].astype(str)
0          00
1          01
2          02
3          10
4          11
5          12
```

Normally I would use `%.2d` but I'm not sure how to do it with pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

> Pad strings in the Series/Index by prepending ‘0’ characters.

```
df[0].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

---

```
0    00
1    01
2    02
3    10
4    11
5    12
```